# How can I find a list of all tickets that are linked to issues that have been resolved?

Tags: jira, jql

I'm using Jira as a test case management system, with each individual test case being represented as a ticket under the Test project.  I have some test case tickets that are linked as "blocked by" to issue tickets in another Jira project.  Some of those issues have since been resolved.  Is there an advanced search query I can use to pull up all the Test tickets which are linked to resolved issues?

Using Jira OnDemand hosted at Atlassian.  I'm open to creative solutions that involve browser automation, Excel, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually do some of this [natively with JQL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-linkedIssues) using the linkedissues() functionality that was introduced in JIRA 4.0:

> **Find issues that are linked to a particular issue:**
>
> `issue in linkedIssues(ABC-123)`
>
> **Find issues that are linked to a particular issue via a particular
>   type of link:**
>
> `issue in linkedIssues(ABC-123,"is duplicated by")`

Unfortunately, the functionality you really need (the ability to query for ALL issues with links of a certain type) is only handled by a plugin called [JQL Tricks Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks%3ajql-plugin) (which you can't install into your hosted JIRA instance). Sorry, but I don't have a great browser automation or Excel solution for you.