# Close Jira Swimlane after last subtask is closed

Tags: task, jira, user-stories

Currently we use swimlanes based on user stories. Having a lot of stories with subtasks makes the board quite unclear.

Is there a way to remove the swimlane for a story where all subtasks have been closed? That way they would return to the "Closed column" and make the board more overseeable. (We close the user story based on the transtion of the subtask, that is not my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Stories are closed, you could just add "AND Status NOT IN ('Closed')" to your swimlane queries. As it is, I think you'll need an addon; this is a lot like other questions about searches based on linked issues. See [JQL to get blocked Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597004/jql-to-get-blocked-issues) and [How can I find a list of all tickets that are linked to issues that have been resolved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779323/how-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-tickets-that-are-linked-to-issues-that-have-been-re)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite exactly what you're asking, but I would try using a Quick Filter to momentarily hide issues that are Closed. The swimlane should disappear if all the issues in it are hidden. So you could use a `status not in (...)` condition in a Quick Filter to suppress your "Done" subtasks and their "Done" parents.

Downside: the need to manually toggle it on. But I don't see a good way around this because the default behavior is to show things on the board even when they're done.

If you're using a Kanban board, theoretically you could simply exclude such tickets from your board's filter query, causing everything to just vanish from the board as soon as it's completed, but obviously that carries with it some issues depending on what steps remain to be performed once tickets arrive at your 'Closed' state.